# How to pass another function as a variable to apply function in R?

Tags: r

So I want to apply a function over a matrix in R. The apply function takes a custom function that takes two parameters: element of a matrix and sum of the row that element belongs to. Below is the reproducible code

```
m = (matrix(1:10, nrow=2))
## Custom Function
IC = function(element, sum_rows){
  value = -log(element/sum_rows,2)
  return(value)
}
```

I am wondering if there is any way of passing rowSums as a parameter to apply function like below

```
apply(m,1:2,IC,sum_rows = rowSums)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applying element-by-element (with `MARGIN = 1:2`), the `rowSums` function won't work because there are no rows.  Each element is an atomic vector.

Fortunately, this operation can be fully vectorized and `log2` can be used for a binary (base 2) logarithm.

```
-log2(m / rowSums(m))
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
# [1,] 4.643856 3.058894 2.321928 1.836501 1.473931
# [2,] 3.906891 2.906891 2.321928 1.906891 1.584963
```